# Updating List Box For Web Browser History

Tags: vb.net

I am making a web browser in Visual Basic and I need the List box with the history to update every time I visit a new page, I have tried `.Refresh()` but it didn't work.

Could you advice?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this on your event.

ListBox1.Items.Clear()